# Integer to letters with a loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program on python that will take 3 integers and convert them into letter's using their ASCII but I'm not sure what is wrong with this program. Can you help me?

```
num = []
letter = []
x = 0
numx = 0
for x in range(0,3):
    numx = int(input('Enter an integer'))
    num.append(numx)
    letter.append(str(chr(num[x]))

print(letter)
```

Comment: Well, `letter.append(str(chr(num[x]))` has unbalanced parentheses

Comment: So, what does it do that it shouldn'?

Comment: and, also `chr` also already gives you a string, so your `str` is superfluous.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it prints '\x01' instead of a letter

Comment: So you entered `1` when an ASCII code was asked? What character did you believe to get?

Comment: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html   start with integers of 33 up to 127- do NOT use 32 - it might   not be visible because its  whitespace...

Comment: @RithikaRavi `\x01` is an escape sequence representing the byte 1. So, you know that `ord('a') == 91`, and we can represent 91 in hexadecimal with 61, so try `print("\x61")`

Comment: "Thank you it's fixed now" edits are generally frowned upon here. Either post an answer of you're own (you're very encouraged to do that!) and accept that, or accept the answer that solved your problem. Or, and that only makes sense when you had a basic mistake that has nothing to do with your question, close/delete your own question. that is a big step, as it invalidates the work of the people who posted answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is just that you only have two closing parens for three open parens in the third line of the loop. Making the change, your code seems to work for me.

Also, since you're doing the append inside the loop, there's no reason to use `num[x]` instead of `numx` directly. Unless you're using it for something else, you can get rid of `num` entirely. And your call to `str` is unnecessary.

Comment: This feels more of a comment/collection of comments than a full answer.

Comment: If the content of this post makes the code in question work, how is this not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To convert ASCII numbers into a string, you could do the following:

```
letters = []

for x in range(0,3):
    numx = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
    letters.append(str(chr(numx)))

print(''.join(letters))
```

For example:

```
Enter an integer: 65
Enter an integer: 66
Enter an integer: 67
ABC
```

`letters` is a list of the numbers converted to letters, and the [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) is used to concatenate them all together (without adding anything between them).